# Can I set a variable to be a multipart property of an object?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I want to be able to set an object property with a variable in a way that lets me make the variable multipart sometimes and single part other times.  The code below doesn't work but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
var mekBldr = {
  mecha: {
    rightLimbs: {
        legs: {
            rightleg01: {
                cost: 0,
                classification: ''
            }
        }
    },
    leftLimbs: {
        legs: {
            leftleg01: {
                cost: 0,
                classification: ''
            }
        }
    }
  }
};

var part1 = 'leftLimbs';

var part2 = 'legs';

var multi = part1[part2];

// the goal: mekBldr.mecha.leftLimbs.legs.leftleg01.cost = 5;

mekBldr.mecha[multi].leftleg01.cost = 5;
```

Comment: No, you can't do that directly; you'd have to write/use code that would allow for such dynamic object graph navigation. (There's at least one old question with some good solutions; I'll look around.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this.

```
Object.prototype.select = function(route) {
    var newObj = this;

    route.forEach(function(key) {
        newObj = newObj[key];
    });

    return newObj;
};
```

You can use the above method like so.

```
var mekBldr = {
    mecha: {
        rightLimbs: {
            legs: {
                rightleg01: {
                    cost: 0,
                    classification: ''
                }
            }
        },
        leftLimbs: {
            legs: {
                leftleg01: {
                    cost: 0,
                    classification: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var part1 = 'leftLimbs';
var part2 = 'legs';

var multi = [part1, part2];

mekBldr.mecha.select(multi).leftleg01.cost = 5;
```

Comment: Very nice. I had to change the "new" variable to another name.  Also, I have to only pass arrays to it.  If I pass a string it breaks.

Comment: Yeah, should have seen that `new` would be a problem, will update my answer. You could just use `a.split(' ')` as an example for strings.

Comment: I hit a big problem with this! It won't run in jQuery.  I had to add:
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'select',{
    value : function() {},
    enumerable : false
});
This stopped the jQuery errors but then it stopped working. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It's not meant to run in jQuery as it is a standard JavaScript object extension. You can of course use it with jQuery but it has nothing to do with the library per se.